# Tossing some coins.

Tags: probability

It is indeed intuitive that the outcome of one coin which has been tossed before another coin does not affect the result of the second coin. But my textbook says

> As you perform the experiment a greater number of times, the empirical probability of getting a head tends to $0.5$....

which makes me think that after getting $10$ tails in a row (by chance) then it is more likely that you get heads in the next few trials because the probability of getting heads should tend to zero.

Where am I erring then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: See [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

Comment: As you divide by successively larger numbers a deviation like the one you initially observed becomes small.

Answer (score 1):

If, purely by chance, with a fair coin it turned out that you got the first 10 flips as tails, then it is still probability 0.5 to get a head in subsequent flips.  The law of large numbers says that initial noise will average out.  Suppose you flip the coin 1000 more times (total 1010).  In those 1000 flips, suppose you now get 497 tails.  The average is close to 0.5 in the subsequent flips, AND, if you look at all 1010 flips, you only got 507 tails, which is again close to 0.5.